# How to add buttons in terminal python

Tags: python, button

Hi I was wondering if i could add buttons in my terminal using python as I am making a project and decided not to use tkinter and other GUI modules. Instead I wanted to do it in the python terminal and for your information I am using a MacBook.

Thanks for any help provided!  ;)

Comment: You want buttons, which are part of a GUI, but not a GUI module. Why not?

Comment: I'm afraid the terminal is just for text. If you want a GUI, you're going to have to create a GUI.

Comment: A button is a graphical element. it's contradicting to have a GUI in a CLI. So to answer in simple words, its not possible to add a button. Instead you can make an interactive CLI program with multiple options that the user can use the arrow keys to select etc. (you may have come across it while installing a few applications via CLI)

Comment: You cannot have buttons on a Command Line. However, you could use user inputs (choices) to simulate what a button does.

Comment: Wait I thought that you could use curses module to create buttons. Just that i dont know how :(